# typescript interface with a generic object parameter

Tags: typescript, object, generics, interface

I have multiple objects in my app. For example:

```
interface Recipe {  
  title: string,  
  ingredients: []  
  creator: string,  
  // ...  
}

interface Vendor {  
  name: string
  address: Address  
  // ...  
}
```

The user should have the ability to create objects that can accept any of these interfaces for example:

```
interface Event<T> {  
  date: Date(),  
  type: T // This should be of type Recipe or Vendor object for example.  
}
```

1. What is the proper way to define this?
2. How would I then find out which object the user passed?

Thank You!

Comment: Hi @Agata! I'm not sure, what do you mean "the proper way to define this"? You already defined correctly an Event which can accept a Generic type. Would you like to force type nly to be one of "Recipe" or "Vendor"?

Comment: Yes. I am also not clear on how to identify which object the user passed?

Comment: You could use [Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQcADig3gKDGDABsIAuZAZzClAHMAafBqCAE2AnCsoG0AuvgRs4YAPZRKNOiCb58AXwWhIsRCgBq3dpOQEQcALYVqtBszjt2bKr2QBBa7apKV4aPCSPnEO-oVlYXEQGmRxACMAK0p0TBxkAB9kbRBdKGQAXgDkXOQiUlMAcgAmAEYi5jzkVg4uHn4BKryRCDFJSiKit2DQsHDoktiMbBRk1PSsnLzDE07K-GqrGz97XGUghBCwyKiAZmH4sZSdPWyCaoKyTvKF6trObjB7QWbc2eKi5AB6b+QsKDiHBQMAAT2QrXaGSMwDsDCUQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know which type the user passed, you need to use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

To do so, you should:

1. Augment the interfaces adding a `kind` or `type`, or whatever you like, property in order to discriminate between them:

```
interface Recipe {  
  type: 'Recipe',
  title: string,  
  ingredients: []  
  creator: string,  
  // ...  
}

interface Vendor {  
  type: 'Vendor',
  name: string
  address: Address  
  // ...  
}
```

2. Define an union type including the available objects

```
type Entity /* or whatever */ = Recipe | Vendor;
```

Now TS can understand which specific interface is used given the type property

3. Define the Event given the union type

```
interface Event<T extends Entity> {  
  date: Date,  
  type: T['type'], // If you need only the type
  object?: T
}

const event: Event<Recipe> = {
  date: Date,
  type: 'recipe',
  object: recipe
}

function <T extends Entity>(event: Event<T>) {
  switch (event.type) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I declare the type. Can you also give me an example how would I instantiate this interface?

Comment: You can declare the type after the interfaces or just before them, it doesn't matter. I'll update the answer with an Event example.

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer satisfy you, please accept it so other users will know it worked.